# Tableau : How to show selected filters in downloaded cross tab

Tags: filter, download, tableau-api, crosstab

My application is a Tableau dashboard. Im allowing the user to select values in drop down filters. 
At the dashboard level the user is aware of the filters selected.
However, when the user downloads the crosstab of the dashboard, none of the filter values show up.

Is there a way to ensure that the selected filters show up in the downloaded crosstab of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place the filtering dimension in the *Mark* card and select *"Detail"*. Now when you export Crosstab to Excel, the filter will be displayed at the first.